# How to add multiple havingCondition with OR operator?

Tags: database

I want to add havingCondition with OR operator

In normal sql query my having conditions are like:

```
group by n.nid
having comment_count!=0 OR viewed_count!=0 OR likes_count!=0;
```

With adding multiple havingConditions like:

```
$query->havingCondition('likes_count', 0, '!=');
$query->havingCondition('viewed_count', 0, '!=');
$query->havingCondition('comment_count', 0, '!=');
```

but It gives having condition with AND operator

Can any one please help me in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create OR conditions separately, in a variable, and then just use them:

```
$or = db_or()->condition('a', 0, '=')->condition('b', 0, '=')->condition('c', 0, '=');
$query->havingCondition($or);
```

For more details, read [`db_or` documentation on Drupal API page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_or/7). This should always be your first place to go, before you ask API-related questions.

Comment: Thanks for the giving answer. I was doing with db_or()->havingCondition('a', 0, '=').